# Check if a column already exists in the table

Tags: java, database, resultset

I need to verify if a column already exists in a table . My class extends CustomTaskChange so my method receives a Database object as an argument. Can I make the verification I want trough the ResultSetObject?

```
@Override
    public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {
    
            JdbcConnection connection = (JdbcConnection) database.getConnection();
            DatabaseMetaData metadata;
            metadata = connection.getMetaData();
            String[] types = {"TABLE"};
            ResultSet rs = metadata.getTables(null, null, "%", types);
            Statement s = connection.createStatement();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    String tableName = rs.getString(3);
                    if (tableName.endsWith(this.suffix)) {
                        String sql = sqlStatement.replaceAll("name", tableName);
                        s.execute(sql);
                    }
                }
    }
```

Basically what this piece of code is doing is going through all the tables in my database. If, a table name ends in a suffix, I will add the column to it. This way I can add a column to multiple tables at the same time.
But I want to add another verification to add the column to a table, and that is that there can't already be a column with that name in that table. Something like this(pseudocode)

```
if(tableName.endsWith(this.suffis) && columnName doesn't exist in that table){
   String sql = sqlStatement.replaceAll("name", tableName);
   s.execute(sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fetch columns from each of the tables then you can check column exist or not.

---

```
 {
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME LIMIT 1");
  ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
  int col = md.getColumnCount();
  for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++){
  String col_name = md.getColumnName(i);
   if(col_name.equals("YourColumnName"){
     /*Then the column already exist*/
 }}
```

Comment: With that code can I delete DatabaseMetadata?

Comment: I think maybe I didn't explained my question well, I will update it

Answer (score 0):

With the above code, you can check the metadata and then execute the SQL query to delete the same.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand

Comment: Something like this,

`if(col_name.equals("YourColumnName"){ 
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
 String sql = "ALTER TABLE <TABLENAME> DROP COLUMN <YourColumnName>";
 stmt.executeUpdate(sql);}`

Comment: but how can I check if the column already exists in the table? My problem is accessing the list of columns in each table. For example, what I want to do is something like this
`while (rs.next){ getColumnsinTable; checkIfColumnNameExisits;`

Comment: `{Connection con = datasource.getConnection();
 Statement st = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TestTable");
 ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
 int col = md.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++){
 String col_name = md.getColumnName(i);
 if(col_name.equals("columnname")){
  String sql = "ALTER TABLE TestTable DROP COLUMN columnname";  
  int queryResult = st.executeUpdate(sql);
  if(queryResult==1)
   System.out.println("column deleted");
  else
   System.out.println("column not found");
   }}

}`

This is a woking code.